# How do list all applications in Graph Explorer with my Azure free account?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to learn Azure directory services, so I created a [free Microsoft Azure account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) to play around with Azure, and then I created a new App registration at `portal.azure.com`. So I have this registered application in Azure with a Client ID, Tenant ID, and even a Client Secret, because I want to learn API permissions with this app.

Now in the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I want to try using API methods like [Get Application and List Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta).

However, if I log in and run the API to list my applications (`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications`), the response has an empty array of applications.

Also if I try to `GET` the specific app that I registered in AD, I get a `404: Resource Not Found` found error.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the Graph Explorer with my test Azure account so my registered application can be retrieved and edited with Microsoft Graph APIs?

*More Details Below*

When I run `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications` in Microsoft Graph Explorer, I expect a list of my applications, including the one app I registered in Azure. Instead, here is the response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#applications",
    "value": []
}
```

When I run `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{client-id}`, with my registered app's client-id, I expect all the details of my registered app, but instead, the response is error 404:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "*****",<--I commented this out
            "date": "2019-05-28T20:17:11"
        }
    }
}
```

If this were a permissions issue, I would expect unauthorized errors instead of "resource not found". I've tried adding Microsoft Graph permissions to my registered App (`Directory.Read.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`), but this hasn't helped.

Comment: Are you authenticating to Graph Explorer using an account from your Azure AD Tenant?

Comment: I log in to graph explorer with {my username}@outlook.com, but this is the same account I log in with at portal.azure.com to see my App registration. Should I be logging into Graph Explorer with a different account?

Comment: Good call, not using an account from my Azure AD Tenant was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Azure free account. If you login in Graph Explorer using outlook account, it will identify this account as a personal account(with tenant outlook.com). That's why you can not find the applications you created in your tenant.

It is recommended to create a new user in your tenant to do the tests.

Here are the steps.

**1**.Click Azure Active Directory->Users->New User. The username should be something like **username@{your tenant name}**(XXX.onmicrosoft.com)

[image]

**2**.After the creation, add the roles for this user.

[image]

Comment: Tony you're a hero. I forgot my tenant but found it by clicking "Azure Active Directory" and then "Overview" and it was on the top left ending in "onmicrosoft.com" like you suggested. I logged in to Graph Explorer as the new user you suggested creating, accepted some extra permissions in Graph Explorer, and now Graph Explorer works with my Azure trial. Thank you.